# `schema.rb` is cleared and set to version `0` when migrations are run

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I have a couple of migrations and an existing `schema.rb`.
I did have the desired table with records in it and at some point in the development process I realised that I could not re-create the migrations.

Now I am running into weird scenarios:

1. When I delete the database and re-run the migrations, no exception is thrown but the migrations are not listed and the table is not created:

   ```
   $ bin/rake db:drop
   $ bin/rake db:create
   $ bin/rake db:migrate
   ```
2. However, when I run the migration, the `schema.rb` which previously contained all the created table now looks like this:

   ```
   ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do

   end
   ```

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/besi/9068fd4635e8dc47fbb6) contains the original `schema.rb` as well as the migrations.

This is my `database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: dev_db
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

**Update**:

I can re-create my database by running `bin/rake db:schema:load`. But as soon as I then run a migration again the whole process is reverted and all the migrations are downgraded and I end up with an empty `schema.rb` once more:

```
$ bin/rails g migration AddBubuToUser bubu:string
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20151203104243_add_bubu_to_user.rb

$ bin/rake db:migrate
== 20151203092755 RemoveNameFromUser: reverting ===============================
-- add_column(:users, :name, :string)
   -> 0.0179s
== 20151203092755 RemoveNameFromUser: reverted (0.0215s) ======================

== 20151203092753 AddNameToUser: reverting ====================================
-- remove_column(:users, :last_name, :string)
   -> 0.0188s
-- remove_column(:users, :first_name, :string)
   -> 0.0176s
== 20151203092753 AddNameToUser: reverted (0.0369s) ===========================

== 20151203091637 AddRoleToUsers: reverting ===================================
-- remove_column(:users, :role, :integer)
   -> 0.0253s
== 20151203091637 AddRoleToUsers: reverted (0.0256s) ==========================

== 20151203091630 AddNameToUsers: reverting ===================================
-- remove_column(:users, :name, :string)
   -> 0.0125s
== 20151203091630 AddNameToUsers: reverted (0.0128s) ==========================

== 20151203091627 DeviseCreateUsers: reverting ================================
-- remove_index(:users, {:column=>:reset_password_token})
   -> 0.0214s
-- remove_index(:users, {:column=>:email})
   -> 0.0200s
-- drop_table(:users)
   -> 0.0010s
== 20151203091627 DeviseCreateUsers: reverted (0.0432s) =======================
```